Dynamically populate dependent, entity reference field with AJAX (dependent dropdown)
Ive looked into the d11 AJAX example and found a similar question on D7 here, but i still cant get it work.
setup:
There are two entity reference fields (competition and players) on the node create page. The user selects the first value from a dropdown (taxonomy term) and this should populate the options for the second dropdown (also an entity reference view).
AJAX works insofar as a second textfield value is set with the selected value form the first dropdown (taxonomy term reference). However, what does not work is setting the selected value as "contextual views filter" for the second, dependent entity reference field. Now, i think getting the first term (target_id) works, but how can i pass it to the second entity reference view (as contextual filter) narrowing down the options the user can select from? my understanding is that in the field settings of the players er field, the "view argument" is static and therefore of no use here?
We have also ECA installed if that is a simpler solution (but not sure if this works well with AJAX), form_states wont work here either i guess as one cannot set values.
The code so far:
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface;


/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for the node form.
 */
function customisations_form_node_matches_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
      \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t('You are editing MATCHES'), 'status');
   $form['field_competition']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
      'callback' => 'auto_populate_field_ajax_callback',
      'event' => 'change',
      'progress' => [
        'type' => 'throbber',
        'message' => t('Updating...'),
      ],
    ];
    // Add wrapper ID to the target field
    if (isset($form['field_players'])) {
      $form['field_players']['#prefix'] = '<div id="field-players-wrapper">';
      $form['field_players']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    }
}

/**
 * AJAX callback to populate the field_players
 */
function auto_populate_field_ajax_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  // Get the selected taxonomy term ID
  $selected_value = $form_state->getValue('field_competition');
  if (!empty($selected_value[0]['target_id'])) {
    // Load the taxonomy term
    $term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
      ->load($selected_value[0]['target_id']);
    
    if ($term) {
      // Get the term name
      $term_name = $term->getName();
      // Update the field_players value
      $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(
        'input[name="field_players[0][value]"]',
        'val',
        [$term_name]
      ));
    }
  }
  return $response;
}


I worked on a similar thing with one of my webforms and implemented the following approach to make it work. I made adjustments based on your requirements. Specifically, I returned the target field through my AJAX callback to ensure it refreshes. This process redirects the control back to hook_form_alter, where I applied logic to check if a value is selected for field_competition. If a value is present, it is used to set the contextual filter value for the target field in the view.
NOTE : Please make sure that field_competition is returning the value in needed type i.e. raw value or array. Update that as per your requirement. You can check that value type by applying logger in form alter. Hope that helps !
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function customisations_form_node_matches_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_competition']['#ajax'] = [
    'callback' => 'updatePlayers',
    'event' => 'change',
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => t('Updating...'),
    ],
    'wrapper' => 'field-players-wrapper', // this should be wrapper id for your player field.
    'disable-refocus' => TRUE,
  ];

  // Add wrapper ID to the target field
  if (isset($form['field_players'])) {
    $form['field_players']['#prefix'] = '<div id="field-players-wrapper">';
    $form['field_players']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  }

  // Set the view contextual filter for players field.
  if(!empty($form_state->getValue('field_competition'))) {
    $form['field_players']['#selection_settings']['view']['arguments'][] = $form_state->getValue('field_competition');
  }
}

/**
 * Ajax callback to update players.
 */
function updatePlayers(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  return $form['field_players'];
}


Thank you for your assistance Jagraj. What do i set in the second players entity reference Views though as contextual filter so that this works? display raw value takes it from the url, no? there is also query parameter as an option, but isnt that also taken from the url?
